# C - format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

I have defined a `vector` of pointers with weekdays. Later on, I want to sort the days `lexicographically`.

I print all the weekdays by using `printf("%s", *(wochentag + i));` which works. I want the output of each first letter of each weekday. Later, I want to also access the second, third, ... letter of each word.

By using

```
printf("%c", *(wochentag + i));`
```

I get the following warning:

```
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat].
```

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
   static char *wochentag[] = {"Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", 
                        "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"};
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(wochentag));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *(wochentag + i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *(wochentag + i));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the format charcter '%c' represents a char (or byte), that can be represented as int, but you are actually dereferencing a string like in printf("%s\n", *(wochentag + i));

Comment: Please do not use `*(arr + i)` to access the elements of an array. Use `arr[i]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory, there is a data type mismatch.

Another syntax of writing `*(wochentag + i)` is `(wochentag[i])`, which is of type `char *`.

Now, passing that to `%c` is wrong, as this conversion specification expects a `char` type.

If you're interested in only the first char, you have to index into that array, like `(wochentag[i][0])`. Something like

```
 printf("%c\n", wochentag[i][0]);
```

should work.

Comment: @M.M: That would be interesting if types included storage class and linkage, and you needed a cast to assign an automatic value to a static lvalue or an internal value to an external thing. 

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Now it works. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In `printf("%c\n", *(wochentag + i))`, `*(wochentag + i)` is a string, more precisely a dereferenced pointer to a string literal (null-terminated read-only byte array), as you can see in your code, you need `"%s"` format specifier.

To print the first `char` in each string you would need an extra dereference:

```
printf("%c\n", **(wochentag + i));
```

Or for a more reader-friendly notation

```
printf("%c\n", wochentag[i][0]);
```

The warning indicating that `"%c"` expects an `int` is because it is indeed expecting the `int` code for the specific character.

A practical example:

```
int x = 65;  //ASCII code for the letter 'A'
printf("%c\n", x);
```

This will output `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array data type char*[] is a type of double pointer so when you print using %s, it knows that it has address of some array of chars but when you print using only '%c' in printf you have to give the actual character but not the address....so you have to de-reference it twice

Like below

```
printf("%c", **(wochentag + i));
```

Hope this answers your problem....peace